# How can I search for an attachment by filename pattern?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

As the title suggests, I can search like so:

```
filename:{asf asx avi divx flv m4v mkv mov mp4 mpeg mpg ogm wmv}
```

Or

```
filename:example.pdf
```

But I want to search on filename with regex. Something like:

```
filename:*ampl*
```

... to find a file named `example.xlsx`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail doesn't recognize special search characters like `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `&`, `#`, `*`, and currency symbols. You can't use these symbols trying to search email or attachments.
On the other hand, Google interprets a string search as part of the contents of an attachment file name.

For example, `filename:monday` would be like `filename:*monday*`, if Google interpreted the characters '*' as a wildcard.